# How to group stream and recive a result (List<Entity> entity, number of Entity elements in collection)

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say that I have an Entity `Item` and `OutOfStockItem` which extend Item.

I have a method basket.getList() which returns List of `Item` and `OutOfStockItems`, all I want to filter `OutOfStockItem` from the list and receive result:

`List<Item>, number of the elements in the left collection`

So far I have a method like:

```
return basket.getList().stream()
                .filter(OutOfStockItem.class::isInstance)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

but it returns Map<Item, Long> which will return a counter for every distinct entity like:

`Item1 = 1;`

`Item2 = 1;`

which is not desirable.
Desirable collection result is:

`(Item1, Item2; 2)`

I will be grateful for suggestions on how to reach a goal.

Comment: Why not just collect to list and use the list size?

Comment: @Eritrean
I did it in that way but thought about combining these two things into a single result from the stream, if there will be no gentle way I will keep it like it is

Comment: @Martin more than the complexity in the implementation, this way you can actually bind by the contract that the size is inferred from the source of truth i.e. `List<OutOfStockItem>` which is desired in the output as well. So, just collect them and use `size` to construct your response object.

Comment: return basket.getList().stream().filter(OutOfStockItem.class::isInstance).collect(Collectors.toList()), then just call size() when needed

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need such a result, but one way could be to use `Collectors.teeing()` (Java 12 or higher)

```
Map<List<Item>,Long> result = 

    basket.getList().stream()
            .filter(OutOfStockItem.class::isInstance)
            .collect(
                 Collectors.teeing(
                     Collectors.toList(), 
                     Collectors.counting(), 
                     (list, count) -> Map.of(list,count)
           ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The output map `(Item1, Item2; 2)` always results in just one entry, so the solution that creates the entry from a list is straightforward and [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) brings no benefit in here.

Just remember the map data structure with a list as a key is strange and unusual.

**Java 9+**

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>(basket.getList());
items.removeIf(item -> !(item instanceof OutOfStockItem));
        
Map<List<Item>, Integer>> map = Map.of(items, items.size());
```

**Java 8**

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>(basket.getList());
items.removeIf(item -> !(item instanceof OutOfStockItem));

Map<List<Item>, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(items, items.size());
```